# Assigning an operation to a special character within a class in Python

Tags: python, numpy, class, methods, operators

So, numpy can call its method "matmul" when multiplying 2 numpy arrays [[1]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) by using the "@" character:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

a@b
```

My question is, can I assign to an unusual character, let's say "$", some method within a class?
For example, let's say I have a class "Fraction", so that when I call Fraction(1,2) $ Fraction(1,2) it returns the sum of the inputs plus 30?

So

`Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(1,2)#will return Fraction(1) (which is equal to 1)`

Then

`Fraction(1,2) $ Fraction(1,2) #I want it to be equal to (Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(1,2) + 30), i.e 1 + 30 = 31`

If It's not possible, how did numpy manage to do it with "@"?

Comment: No.  Operators like `+` and `@` are part of the Python syntax, that the interpreter translates to calls of methods like `__add__` and `__matmul`__`.  Your class can implement custom versions of those methods, but can't define new operators.